# Cart crossell products on PDP

Tags: magento2.4, shopping-cart, cross-sells, adobe-commerce, pdp

I'm using magento 2.4.6 and I want display the crosssell products that is set using cart-product rule on PDP. Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to develop custom extension or use a 3rd part auto related product extension if you want it to be based on cart conditions. Check this extension - https://magefan.com/magento-2-automatic-related-products

Comment: There's adobe's AI product recommendation tool for that